# Office 16 File Extensions not recognised by MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

Operating system is Windows 7. Recently offered updates to Office 2016 would not install so I reinstalled Office 2016. Reinstall worked but procedures in MS Access no longer work. I.E when trying to open a docx or xlsx file nothing happens; no error messages. A procedure designed to create a word file creates rtf. If I change the file extension of the files to .doc or .xls, things work. Docx and xlsx files open normally if opened directly, i.e. not via an Access procedure. Have done a “Quick Repair” of Office. Have decompiled Access.

Answer (score 0):

In Control Panel/Default Programs, there is:"Set default programs". In Access, Excel and Word I made sure that all extensions were selected.